# Interacting with a serial port using the C functions fopen, fread, and fwrite?

Tags: c, file-io, serial-port

I have been attempting to communicate with a device of mine via an RS232 serial port(in my case it is COM6). My code is supposed to write a string of ascii values to the device and then read the response, however I cannot seem to get any response. The program seems to work relatively fine when I have it write and read to a file in my computer, but not for when I designate COM6. Here is the latest edition of my code:

```
using namespace std;

const char ASCII[ ]= "0123456789ABCDEF";
char *Checksum (char *buffer)
{
static char Hex[10];
static int a1, a2;
register unsigned int i;
int sum;
printf("%s \n", buffer);
sum = 256;
for ( i=0 ; i<strlen(buffer) ; i++ )
{
sum-=buffer[i];
if ( sum<0 )
sum+= 256;
}
a1 = (sum & 0xF0) >> 4;
a2 = sum & 0x0F;
Hex[0] = ASCII[a1];
Hex[1] = ASCII[a2];
Hex[2] = 0;
printf("the checksum is %s \n",Hex);
return(Hex);
}


int main()
{
char data[80], input[80], *data2;
char *response;
DCB dcb;
bool retVal;
DWORD dwBytesTransferred;
DWORD byteswritten;
printf("the variable response is initially: %d\n", response);

dcb.BaudRate = CBR_19200; //19200 Baud
dcb.ByteSize = 8; //8 data bits
dcb.Parity = NOPARITY; //no parity
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; //1 stop

//New open port area
HANDLE        hPort;
  if ((hPort = CreateFile ( "\\\\.\\COM6",
      GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
      0,              // exclusive access
      NULL,           // no security attrs
      OPEN_EXISTING,
      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
      NULL)) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
      printf("SUCCESS opening the port\n");// success
  } 
//GetCommState
DCB Dcb;
  GetCommState (hPort, &Dcb);
  Dcb.BaudRate        = CBR_19200;
  Dcb.StopBits        = ONESTOPBIT;
  Dcb.ByteSize        = 8;
  Dcb.Parity          = NOPARITY;
  Dcb.fParity         = 0;
  Dcb.fOutxCtsFlow    = 0;
  Dcb.fOutxDsrFlow    = 0;
  Dcb.fDsrSensitivity = 0;
  Dcb.fTXContinueOnXoff = TRUE;
  Dcb.fOutX           = 0;
  Dcb.fInX            = 0;
  Dcb.fNull           = 0;
  Dcb.fErrorChar      = 0;
  Dcb.fAbortOnError   = 0;
  Dcb.fRtsControl     = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
  Dcb.fDtrControl     = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;

//Flushing

FlushFileBuffers( hPort );
  PurgeComm (hPort, PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);
  COMSTAT     comStat;
  DWORD       dwErrorFlags;
  ClearCommError ( hPort, &dwErrorFlags, &comStat );

//NEW commtimeouts area
COMMTIMEOUTS CommTimeOuts;
 DWORD dwTimeout = 3000;  // <- set timeout in milliseconds
     if(!dwTimeout)
     {   // Don't use timeout -> Read the bytes already in input buffer and return immediately
         CommTimeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout      = MAXDWORD;
         CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
     } else
     {   // Use given timeout, wait until the requested number of bytes are read - or timeout
         CommTimeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout         = 0;
         CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant    = dwTimeout;
     }
     CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 0;
     CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
     CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant   = 0;
     SetCommTimeouts (hPort, &CommTimeOuts);
printf("insert ASCII code string you wish to send:");
scanf("%s", input);
strcpy(data, "{0x02}");
strcat(data, input);
printf("%s \n", data);
data2=Checksum(data);
strcat(data, data2);
strcat(data, "{0x03}");
printf("the final sent message will be: %s \n",data);
retVal = WriteFile(hPort,data, strlen(data), &byteswritten, NULL);
printf("Number of bytes written: %d\n",  byteswritten);
printf("Write Success? %d\n", retVal);
retVal=ReadFile (hPort, &response, 20, &dwBytesTransferred, NULL);
printf("Read Success? %d\n", retVal);
printf("Port Response: %d\n", response);
free(response);
return 0;
}
```

Summary of latest discoveries: Using the Free Serial Port Monitor that Habi suggested I now know for sure that WriteFile is functioning correctly and COM6 is in receiving the message. I'm still looking for a crossover cable to double check that the message is being transferred across the line. I figure while I try to figure that out if someone could look at this new edition and tell me if there is anything wrong, particularly in relation to the ReadFile function, it would be much appreciated.  It bothers me that the Free Serial Port software is only showing the data passed from my computer and not a response from the device at all. =\

Comment: You really should be using the Win32 API (`CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, and `WriteFile`) for this.  stdio file streams buffer the data unless you tell it not to with [`setvbuf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) or by flushing it with [`fflush(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush).  Also you cannot `fseek`/`ftell` on a serial port, I guarantee you those calls are failing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
"COM6"
```

try

```
"\\\\.\\COM6"
```

And I would recommend to use `CreateFile(), ReadFile(), WriteFile()`.

To open the COM port try this:

```
HANDLE        hComDev;

if ((hComDev = CreateFile ( "\\\\.\\COM6",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,              // exclusive access
    NULL,           // no security attrs
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL)) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
      // success
}
```

It seems that calling `GetCommState()` is missing in your code. Try this to configure the COM port:

```
DCB Dcb;

GetCommState (hComDev, &Dcb); 

Dcb.BaudRate        = CBR_19200;
Dcb.StopBits        = ONESTOPBIT;
Dcb.ByteSize        = 8;
Dcb.Parity          = NOPARITY;
Dcb.fParity         = 0;
Dcb.fOutxCtsFlow    = 0;
Dcb.fOutxDsrFlow    = 0;
Dcb.fDsrSensitivity = 0;
Dcb.fTXContinueOnXoff = TRUE;
Dcb.fOutX           = 0;
Dcb.fInX            = 0;
Dcb.fNull           = 0;
Dcb.fErrorChar      = 0;
Dcb.fAbortOnError   = 0;
Dcb.fRtsControl     = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
Dcb.fDtrControl     = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
```

And to initially clear the COM port, I would do a reset like this before starting to send and receive bytes:

```
FlushFileBuffers( hComDev );

PurgeComm (hComDev, PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);

COMSTAT     comStat;
DWORD       dwErrorFlags;
ClearCommError ( hComDev, &dwErrorFlags, &comStat );
```

You ask for timeouts? To configure time outs try this:

```
COMMTIMEOUTS CommTimeOuts;
DWORD dwTimeout = ....  // <- set timeout in milliseconds

if(!dwTimeout)
{   // Don't use timeout -> Read the bytes already in input buffer and return immediately
    CommTimeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout      = MAXDWORD;
    CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
}
else
{   // Use given timeout, wait until the requested number of bytes are read - or timeout
    CommTimeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout         = 0;
    CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant    = dwTimeout;
}
CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 0;
CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant   = 0;

SetCommTimeouts (hComDev, &CommTimeOuts);
```

> My code is supposed to write a string of ascii values to the device
>   and then read the response, however I cannot seem to get any response.

Are you sure that the bytes are really sent to the device? If you have the option, take a oscilloscope and monitor the PC's Tx line. Send some bytes and check baudrate and start/stop bits. If you have no hardware to monitor this signal, take a software based serial monitor, e.g. [Free Serial Port Monitor](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/). I have no experience with that kind of software tools but they should show you at least that the Windows drivers try to send something via the COM port of your choice.

Greetings
  Habi

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to give that a try. It looks slightly different from my other attempts at using Win32 API functions, so maybe it'll address whatever might have been causing the issue, or at least get me closer. I really appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Thanks for directing me toward the Free Serial Port Monitor! That helped assure me that the WriteFile was at least sending to COM6. I edited my question to reflect the new version of my program.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been trying for a month then I would recommend you look at the windows function [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I have used this for serial port comms and it works fine. You might also want to look at the DCB struct and `GetCommState` and `SetCommState` functions to configure the serial port. `WriteFile` can be used to write data to the serial port. I cannot post all of my code as it owned by my company, but this should help you get started.

Also `ClearCommError` may be of help to you to query if any data is on the serial port buffer when you are waiting to read from it.

Comment: I'm sorry I mistyped on the bottom there, I meant CreateFile, not openfile.  And I used GetCommState and SetCommState too. However the ReadFile function returned nothing (it reported that it read nothing and its buffer was unchanged). ClearCommError might come in handy though, thanks for that pointer.

Comment: @user1569340 well you could try the ClearCommError to see if there is actually any data present on the buffer. You know for sure that the other application that sends your reply accross the serial port works?

Comment: I unfortunately have no idea for sure. WriteFile returns as though it were successful however my device remains unresponsive. It could be possible that I am sending it an erroneous command (which would not be a surprise because it seems like the producers of it intentionally wrote very vague instructions on the syntax of these commands, likely to encourage the purchase of more of their software to do it for you...), However the instructions do indicate that I should get a "Not Aknowledged" response should that occur. So my general impression is that Writefile most likely is not succeeding.

Comment: Hmm it sounds like you could be doing all the right things but not getting a response. If I were you if at all possible I would set up another machine, connect to the serial port of that using a cross-over cable and write a serial port reading application (it doesnt take much code). This way you will see for sure what if your write succeeds. The WriteFile function should return the number of bytes written - do you check that? Is it possible that you need to take endianness into account ???? I only ask these questions as I was in the same position as you not so long ago.

Comment: And another thing, check again all of the configuration options and make sure that they are what they should be

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to see if I can get myself a cross over cable and try that. And I'm unfortunately still a relatively naive programmer so I'm not exactly surewhat you mean by taking endianness into account? I really appreciate the help though! It's been a headache just getting this far without any.

Comment: endianness refers to the byte order. For example I had to code a modbus serial port comms device. modbus is a big endian protocol, but PCs are little endian. Wiki it - I doubt it is a problem but you never know. At least testing on another machine gives you a sanity check to see if you are writing out what you think you are. good luck anyway

Comment: I'll have to do some research into that. The device's user manual doesn't seem to indicate which endian protocal it uses, so I'm going to assume it's little endian, but knowing how many critical details this manual lacks it would not surprise me if they played that trick on me. I found a serial port monitoring software that is telling me that the write is working though, but I think i'm still going to get my hands on a crossover cable to be double sure. I edited my question to reflect my latest program. I'm getting the feeling that maybe I'm just sending the wrong message or something.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and found the other answers helpful, but I was not receiving characters.

Ultimately I found the problem was with RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE or DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE.

By having RTS and DTR held low, the program was indicating to the modem/device that the program was not ready to receive data, and the modem was respecting this signal and dutifully not sending.

By changing these to RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE and DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE, the program indicates to the modem that data may be sent, and I began receiving characters.  Not all devices respect these signals so it may work in some configurations with DTR and RTS disabled -- the modem may send data anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you need to config com port via cmd mode command,
and there is no way to config timeout value via cmd command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // use mode command to config port
    // mode com2 dtr=off rts=off baud=9600 parity=N data=8 stop=1 to=on
    FILE *f = fopen("\\\\.\\COM2", "wb+");
    setvbuf(f, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    if(f == NULL) return -1;
    while(1)
    {
        static char p[5];
        int cnt = fread(&p, 1, sizeof(p), f);
        
        printf("read[%d]:%s\n", cnt, p);
        if(p[0] == '0') break;
        memset(p, 0, sizeof(p));
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```